# Wifi still going dead on upgrade from iOS 6?

Tags: wifi, iphone

Having read about instances of wifi chips going dead on iOS upgrade, and knowing someone who had this happen 2-3 years ago, I have delayed upgrading the iOS on my iphone4.  I am at iOS 6.

Has this problem been fixed or averted in iOS versions currently available?

---

**tl;dr:** Could my Wifi chip go dead when I upgrade my iPhone 4 from iOS 6 to iOS 7?

Answer (score 2):

No-one here can give you a 100% definitive answer to a question starting with *Could...* (if you get what I mean).

However, what I can tell you is that in most cases where an iPhone's Wi-Fi has seemingly stopped working after an iOS update/upgrade, they can be readily resolved by the user. In those rare cases where the issue has been hardware related, the iOS update/upgrade has only acted to aggravate a pre-existing problem.

If you have a compelling reason to upgrade your iPhone 4 to iOS 7, then do it. However, as always, be sure you **do a full backup first**. Also, in case you aren't already aware, the latest version of iOS officially supported on the iPhone 4 is iOS 7.1.2.

Finally, if you do decide to upgrade and find you do have issues with your Wi-Fi, then feel free to post another question here for help.

Comment: Do you have a source for "most cases"?

Comment: Good question. Everytime a new version of iOS is released there are reports of devices no longer working with Wi-Fi. Issues such as this pop up all over the place (e.g. Apple Discussions, news articles, etc) and in most cases they are resolved by common actions (such as a reset of network settings, a reset of all settings, etc). So, I guess when I say _in most cases_ this is based on personal experience (I've lost count of how many iPhones I've troubleshooted) and the fact that following many discussions/forums/etc where these issues are raised I've found that users usually get a resolution.